# How to write only one symbol in input?

Tags: javascript

I want to limit input field to one letter only(with JS),after one I want to get an error. How to do it?

Comment: use the oninput event. limit the length to 1

Comment: show the code and error please

Comment: why not use a pattern like: "^.{1}$" in the input field? instead of check the error in js

Answer (score 1):

You will want something like this

**Vanilla JS**

```
<input onkeydown="checkLen(this)" type="text" maxlength="1" />

function checkLen(e) {
  if (el.value.length > 1) {
    alert("ERROR");
  }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#input').keydown( function(e){
    if ($(this).val().length > 1) { 
        alert('ERROR');
    }
});
```